# Percentage floated grid layout sub-pixel bug

Tags: html, css, css-float, grid-layout

I have a CSS only grid. The width is a percentage and the height is padding-bottom (also percentage).

Sub-pixel window widths are the problem - on an even number width it looks great, on an odd number the bottom square items stack wrongly.

There's screenshots below and I've created a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ts0h6LLr/).

A fix would be to create 'rows' which wrap around the two sections, but as these are generated from an external source that's not possible.

Perhaps padding-bottom isn't the way to do it.. open to suggestions. I've tried a JS option Isotope, however it had the same problem.

```
.grid {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 200px;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;

  span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
  }

  &.type-1 {
    width: 50%;
   padding-bottom: 68%;
  }

  &.type-2 {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 34%;
  }

  &.type-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding-bottom: 33.33%;
  }
}


<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item type-1"><span></span></div>
  <div class="grid-item type-2"><span></span></div>
  <div class="grid-item type-2"><span></span></div>
  <div class="grid-item type-3"><span></span></div>
  <div class="grid-item type-3"><span></span></div>
  <div class="grid-item type-3"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

[image: Correct (even)]

[image: Incorrect (odd)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid will maintain that layout you could try:

```
.grid-item:nth-child(4) {
  clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwxft9d4/

The problem seems to be the first element. If you give that `padding-bottom:67.9%` it works too..

Comment: The layout will change so clear isn't ideal - the 67.9% fix seems to work so thanks for that. I'll update here if I ever find an issue with it but I've just tested the Fiddle back to IE9 and it looks good :)